# Removing Special Character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');

Can anyone Explain this snippet (/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')  ???
What it means?
I know what it does. But how

Comment: It is [Regular Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp). I don't think this question deserves downvotes because one would never know how to search a thing if they totally have no idea what it is. Just like trying to look up a word in dictionary without knowing the spelling. Someone has to tell them how to spell the word.

Comment: It is a regular expression that finds the specific pattern which matches in your string and replaces it with ''.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet

```js
string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
```

Uses RegEx (Regular Expression) to find a paten and then replace it.

This is how it works:

1. The .replace function replaces a specific character or patern in a string (first argument) with another (second argument)
2. The `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g` is the regex. `a-z` means lower case characters from a-z, `A-Z` means upper case characters from a-z and `0-9` means number characters from 0-9. The `^` means not, so, not a letter, uppercase letter or number. The `g` at the end stands for global meaning it will not just find one match for the patern but all the matches
3. The empty string is what to replace the patern with. So if it is not a upper/lower case letter or number character it will be replaced with nothing

Read about [RegEx here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)